# Enlarging image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, image-enlarge

I have a `WPF` application which checks for new images in a certain parent directory, and if there are new images, it switches the currently displayed images (I have 6 images).

I would like to add a feature which will allow a user to click on one of the images, and upon that click, a 'new' window will appear, showing that image enlarged, and another click anywhere on the screen will quit this enlargement and put the focus back to the other (6) images.

Is that possible? I tried googling `zoom image wpf` but found only `mouse-drag` related solutions.

I also tried using `viewport` but that didn't to work so well either.

**Update - XAML**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <GroupBox  x:Name="AccuracyGraphsGroupBox" Header="Accuracy" Foreground="Red">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="AccuracyPicBox" MouseUp="AccuracyPicBox_OnMouseUp"></Image>
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="AccuracyPerioPicBox" MouseUp="AccuracyPerioPicBox_OnMouseUp"></Image>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Just create an `<Image>` with the appropriate size. The default settings will scale the picture up so it fits the bounds.

Comment: you should make this into an answer Nico - just add a bit of XAML to show the relevant properties

Comment: I have the `<Image>` with the sizes set to `Auto`, inside a group box. I would like to add the `MouseUp` event to it, and when the event is captured, I would like to show this image, enlarged, but keep the original image in place. I'm editing my question with the current `Xaml`.

Comment: @Idanis sounds like popup would be a better solution

Comment: Check this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f100d/popup-window-in-wpf/

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 7):

As the guys mentioned in the comments, your best bet is to use a `ToolTip` to popup your full size image. There is a slight problem with data binding the `Image.Source` value from the original `Image` in your `ToolTip`, because they are not part of the normal UI visual tree and exist in their own tree. However, we can overcome this by using the [`ToolTip.PlacementTarget` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Image Name="Image" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Tulips.jpg" Height="100"
    Stretch="Uniform">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5,7,5,5">
                <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Stretch="None" />
            </Border>
        </ToolTip>
    </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Of course, you *could* just use the same `Binding Path` in both `Image.Source` properties, but I never like repeating code.